# How to Render Graph in Python using graphviz and anytree packages

Tags: python-3.x, graphviz, anytree

I'm following this [documentation](https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) of anytree package to render the graph. Please note i have install graphviz on my mac using

```
pip3 install graphviz
```

When I try to execute this

```
RenderTreeGraph(udo).to_picture("udo.png")
```

Im getting following errors

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       RenderTreeGraph(udo).to_picture("udo.png")
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anytree/dotexport.py", line 51, in to_picture
>       check_call(cmd)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 286, in check_call
>       retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 267, in call
>       with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 707, in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
>       raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
>   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dot'

please help me render tree

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was getting the same error. I also used pip3 to install graphviz. But when I installed graphviz using following command, it solved my issue.

```
sudo apt install graphviz
```

Comment: Same.  Thanks very much for posting.   It's a little disconcerting to me that pip3 install and apt install do different things.

Answer (score 2):

Please do the following steps:

1. Determine where `graphviz` is installed. Typically there is a `bin` subdirectory. Copy the path to location where the file `dot` is located. (Just the directory)
2. Edit your `PATH` variable and append the path from above. Please ask google how to do this on your machine.

HTH